# Magento: Warning in PHP in default Adminhtml controller

Tags: magento

When debugging Magento, I found this strange warning.

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  in /mnt/www/t2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 508

In the function checkforSqlInjectionInAction()

From my understanding this warning comes when you cannot open a connection to the database. However in my configuration, I am not using local server, hence this is natural that we cannot connect to the local server.

This warning is in the checkforSqlInjectionInAction().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of debugging someone else's Magento code.   The core Magento code doesn't contain a method named `checkforSqlInjectionInAction`, so you're already dealing with a core hack created by someone else's code.

As for your specific error, `mysql_real_escape_string` will ask the MySQL database what the correct escape character sequence is.  However, this function was designed to work with PHP's original MySQL module

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Since Magento doesn't use mysql_connect, PHP attempts to creation a connection using the default `'apache'@'localhost'` username, with no password.

You should be making your SQL statements using either raw PDO, or the read/write Magento connection resources.  These objects allow you to create queries with bound paramaters, where there's no need to manually escape a database string.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I did not realise this was a hack in the code for SQLinjection. In that case I will be removing it.

Comment: BTW, I would be interested in knowing the security against SQL injection that is implemented in Mangento...